# Cypress fixtures usage in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, testing, cypress

I have used Cypress with Javascript specs and recently switched to Typescript. While using Fixtures, I had the below approach working in Javascript; but, with Typescript I face some difficulty.

**Fixture JSON file:**

I have my fixture file in `/cypress/fixtures/sql_queries.json`

```
{
    "query_1": "SELECT * FROM TABLE_1",
    "query_2": "SELECT * FROM TABLE_2",
}
```

**Before:**

```
before('Load data to fixture', () => {
     cy.fixture('sql_queries')
         .as('sqlQueries')
})
```

**Test spec:**

I'm consuming the loaded fixture file in below sample test,

```
it('Test something', () => {
     cy.get('@sqlQueries')
         .then((queries) => {
             cy.log(queries.query_1)
         })
})
```

**Problem:**

I'm getting the error as `Property 'query_1' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type definitions seem to think your `alias` was of an element.Try adding a type on the parameter to the function passed to `.then`:

```
.then((queries:any) => {
```

Comment: I have the exact scenario and the tests run fine but my IDE shows the errors listed above. If I add
    `.then((queries: any) => {})`
instead of 
    `.then(queries => {})`

It then removes the error from my IDE but then the tests fail and displays that their was a ParseError: Uneexpected Token at  `:any`